# Make custom flutter widget deprecated

Tags: flutter, widget, deprecated

how can I make my own flutter widget / flutter class deprecated (so that when I or anyone else uses the class as a widget that there is a deprecated annotation)?

Here's my current code: https://gist.github.com/janhecker/538a8f0610a29e6be6c7fbce1f525d39

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this on top of your widget:

```dart
@Deprecated('Use this other widget instead')
class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget { ... }
```